# Do not show mapped command in command line

Tags: command-line

I am using

```
nnoremap <esc> :noh<return><esc>
```

to remove the highlighting after a search with `hlsearch` on.

Pressing `<esc>`, this shows `:noh` in the command line. I would like to turn this off (preferably without any side effects).

Comment: Does replacing <return> with <cr> work?

Comment: See `:h map-silent`

Comment: Great, using `<silent>` does it!

Comment: @VanLaser If neither of you adds this as an answer, I'm going to. (Having solved issues in "Unanswered" is untidy!)

Comment: From my point, do it :)

Comment: @jpmath Regarding clearing highlights with `<Esc>`, you might like to read the following question and its answers, too: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2614/why-does-this-esc-nmap-affect-startup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @VanLaser [mentions in a comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5845/do-not-show-mapped-command-in-command-line#comment9550_5845), you can do this by adding `<silent>` to your map command:

```
nnoremap <silent> <esc> :noh<return><esc>
```

[`:help :map-silent`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Amap-silent) explains:

> To define a mapping which will not be echoed on the command line, add "`<silent>`" as the first argument.  Example:
>
> ```
> :map <silent> ,h /Header<CR>
> ```
>
> The search string will not be echoed when using this mapping.  Messages from the executed command are still given though.  To shut them up too, add a ":silent" in the executed command:
>
> ```
> :map <silent> ,h :exe ":silent normal /Header\r"<CR>
> ```
>
> Prompts will still be given, e.g., for inputdialog().
>
> Using "`<silent>`" for an abbreviation is possible, but will cause redrawing of the command line to fail.