# What is making my configuration enter operator pending mode on new session?

Tags: vimrc, autocmd

I've been reading through [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/) and trying some exercises. When I got into the autocommands/autogroups part, I've thought of creating an autocommand to automatically trim trailing white spaces from my C files. So I created the appropriate section on my `.vimrc` file and tested with a simple `test.c` program. The behavior is that when I write the file, the trailing spaces get deleted correctly. But if I write and quit Vim with `ZZ` or `:wq`, and then open the file again with `vim test.c` to check the results, the next key press deletes some characters. With I press `j`, it will delete to the next line, if I press `k` to the previous one. It's like I've just pressed `d` and I'm in operator pending mode for deletion.

What am I doing wrong?

My `~/.vimrc`:

```
set number relativenumber
set hlsearch incsearch nowrapscan nowrap
set showcmd
set wildmenu wildignorecase complete+=d
set path+=**
set sidescroll=1 sidescrolloff=10

nnoremap <Leader>ev :split $MYVIMRC<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>sv :source $MYVIMRC<CR>
inoremap jk <Esc>
map <Leader>y "+y

noremap <Esc> <Nop>

augroup Ccfg
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType c setlocal listchars=trail:.,tab:>-,extends:>,precedes:< list
    autocmd FileType c setlocal tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 shiftround expandtab
    autocmd FileType c setlocal textwidth=80 colorcolumn=+1
    autocmd FileType c setlocal tagcase=match
    autocmd FileType c setlocal cscopetag
    autocmd FileType c setlocal breakindent
    autocmd FileType c iabbrev /*-*/ /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    autocmd BufWrite *.c,*.cpp,*.h %s/\v\s+$//e
augroup END
```

My `test.c` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");    
    return 0;
}
```

Notice the trailing spaces after the `printf` call.

I'm trying to find a way to record my terminal session, but since I'm on Windows using Git Bash and it's Vim, I can't use [asciinema](https://asciinema.org/) or other solutions.

Comment: I've found out by trying different configurations that the culprit is the `noremap <Esc> <Nop>` line. Don't know why, though.

Comment: thats a weird mapping that is known to break some things. Ill look for a reference; in the meantime, you could self-answer if removing that line fixed your problem?

Comment: Here it is : [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530851/why-does-the-combination-of-remapping-esc-to-nop-cause-strange-characters-to) — basically its because of the way terminal emulators process certain things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out by trying different configurations that the culprit is the `noremap <Esc> <Nop>` line.

Thanks to @D. Ben Knoble for finding [Why does the combination of remapping  to  cause strange characters to be automatically inserted when starting vim with startinsert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530851/why-does-the-combination-of-remapping-esc-to-nop-cause-strange-characters-to) that explains that `Esc` is part of many special key combinations and remapping it to `Nop` interfere with those.

Comment: See [my answer here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2614/why-does-this-esc-normal-mode-mapping-affect-startup?rq=1) if you want to keep using that escape mapping.

Comment: Although... try [@Jerome-Dalbert's solution](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15572/343) first!