# Mapping ESC key to toggle command/insert modes

Tags: key-bindings

I want to do wht is asked here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43693204/making-esc-key-toggle-command-insert-modes-in-vim

However, if I follow the answer there, every time I run vim it starts in insert mode and inserts `[2;2R`

I am using vim8.0 on Ubuntu 18 in the GNOME terminal running the Bash shell.

Comment: See https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2620/71

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I can't get any of this to work. Do you have a specific solution you'd suggest? The closest I found that actually worked is to redefine <Esc> upon entering insert mode the first time. This would infuriate me. If I end up using  <Esc> to enter insert mode, then it'd drive me crazy that it never works the first time

Comment: I would simply not re-map the escape key. You could try to map it in a VimEnter autocommand, or using a timer, but those are all hacks in my opinion.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I don't mind hacks, I'm new to vim and this would just help me learn. Probably it won't stick with me anyway, but it's frustrating not being able to try. I tried VimEnter unsuccessfully.

Comment: If you are new to Vim, I suggest going with the default ESC as everybody else ;)