# Why does terminal vim enter replace mode with my vimrc file?

Tags: vimrc, terminal, macos

I mostly use MacVim, but sometimes I'm in the terminal and use the CLI vim.

I recently decided to clean up my vimrc file, retaining only what I knew I wanted. It works fine with MacVim, but when I launch `vim` from the terminal, it works, but does two things MacVim doesn't:

- Beeps
- Places me in Replace mode

[D. Ben Knoble](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/10604/d-ben-knoble) helped me track down that it has to do with the following line:

```
nnoremap <ESC> :nohlsearch<RETURN><ESC>
```

When I remove that line, the problem does disappear. But I do like the behavior it gives me (removing highlighted searches when I hit `<ESC>`).

So, why does that line cause the problem, and is there a way to get what I want with it that doesn't cause a problem?

Here's my [vimrc file on GitHub](https://github.com/chivalry/vimrc/blob/master/vimrc):

Comment: It might have to do with your `<Esc>` remap

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, I did find the `vim -u NONE` on Google, and launching it makes the problem disappear in the CL vim. There are no plugins other than a color scheme file. I removed them all when I began cleaning up the file.

Comment: What about `vim -u DEFAULTS` ? I think thats a thing... it may have a different name

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, that does appear to be it. I deleted the <ESC> remap line, and the problem disappeared. Of course, the next question is, why does that remap cause the problem, and then, is there a better way to remove search highlighting when I press <ESC>?

Comment: I cant figure out how to retract the close vote, but I would [edit] your question to ask that much more specific question.

Comment: Possible alternative: Use a function key to toggle hlsearch. I have the following in my `vimrc`: `nnoremap  <F8>   :set invhlsearch hlsearch?<CR>`.

Comment: :verbose map <esc> ?

Comment: :verbose autocmd

Comment: If you’re still interested in *why* the issue occurred, check out the answers here: [Why does this <Esc> normal mode mapping affect startup?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2614/why-does-this-esc-normal-mode-mapping-affect-startup)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*If you are seeing a similar issue and using Windows Terminal jump down to the "Update" below.*

Seeing `<ESC>` used as the LHS of a key mapping causes me some discomfort. You've demonstrated one reason why...it doesn't seem to work right in a vimrc file. It doesn't matter what you have on the RHS, the LHS `<ESC>` causes some characters (maybe related to the underlying key code for `<ESC>`) to be emitted as if they were Normal mode commands and those include `2R`. (If you type something right after entering Vim and hit escape you'll see the typed string replace current text twice.)

My first bit of advice would be to save the headaches and use a different key for mapping. If you really want to use `<ESC>` then continue...

My first instinct while trying to fix things was to use an `autocommand` to delay the setup of the mapping but that doesn't help. It's still in the context that doesn't play nice with LHS `<ESC>`

My second notion was to also use an `autocommand` but with an asynchronous call since these calls occur in a different context (i.e. when Vim's thread has entered an idle state). Turns out, it works...

```
func! EscMapSetup(timerid)
    nnoremap <ESC> :nohlsearch<CR><ESC>
endfunc

autocmd VimEnter * call timer_start(100, 'EscMapSetup')
```

Has that hack smell to it but if someone can't come up with the root cause of this issue and a clean way around it this isn't too bad...at least it doesn't require any particular timing; the 100ms above is an arbitrarily chosen number of short duration.

**BTW**...
What is the purpose of the `<ESC>` on the RHS of the mapping? You're already in Normal mode so it doesn't do anything there. Only thing I can think of is you want to clear the command line of the `nohlsearch` text that lingers there. If so, consider using `<C-L>` in it's place. That will redraw the screen after cleaning it...that leaves a pristine c/l...and no more flirting with problems that the special status of `<ESC>` sometimes bears.

**2020-12-05 Update:** Per the numerous comments below [Command already typed in when I open vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/28269/command-already-typed-in-when-i-open-vim) there is a bug, since fixed and released in September, in the Windows Terminal terminal emulator.

You can either get the latest version of WT or you can try an alternate terminal emulator. I personally use and like mintty.

There is also a workaround that appears to be benign: `:set t_u7=`

In short the problem is how WT handles the control sequence contained in `'t_u7'`. This control sequence, valid only for xterm-compatible terminal emulators, is used to get the cursor's position. Vim sends the sequence to the terminal on startup under certain conditions (i.e. if using utf-8 `'encoding'` or similar) to find out how wide characters are represented. When WT responds it mixes the answer with the response to a separate control sequence such that individual characters are intermingled rendering the whole thing invalid and causing Vim to think it's normal user input. It so happens that the last two characters are *usually* `2R` which explains why things behave as if you entered that Normal mode command.

See also

- [Windows Terminal bug details](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/1637)
- [Original defect filed against Vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/6365)

Comment: I liked that pressing `<ESC>` had the dual effect of getting into normal mode and removing search highlights if there were any. It's not a huge deal, and for now I've replaced the original map with `nnoremap <Leader><SPACE> :nohlsearch<CR>`.

Comment: Hi @Chuck. Something sounds not quite right here. An `nmap` mapping is only triggered if you're in Normal mode, right? Your mapping is ignored for `<ESC>` in other modes....we just get the native escape key behavior. Also, as I touched on in the last part of my answer, the `<ESC>` on the RHS of your mapping is unnecessary because `<CR>` while on command-line will take you to Normal mode after any command(s) were run. Are you seeing anything to contradict this? ....

Comment: ....You've decided to use a different mapping, which is probably the wisest choice, so you don't need to do anything else but if interested get back to me. Cheers.

Comment: This is much nicer than my `InsertEnter` hack! (In my defence, the timers feature hadn’t been implemented when I came up with mine.)

Comment: @Rich Yes, I suppose that could serve as somewhat of a hindrance to you arriving at the same solution as I did. :)

Comment: Tried this. Vim works with glitches. Cannot be used. Checked in standard bash terminal on Ubuntu 20.04 with Vim version: VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1.
When in insert mode moving cursor is not properly working (arrows, page up, page down). For example, instead of arrow down symbol B is inserted (in insert mode and sometimes in normal mode). Instead of Page Down symbol F is inserted.

Comment: @AntonSamokat It appears that Rich has addressed your issue in the duplicate thread.