# Command already typed in when I open vim

Tags: vimrc

When I open up vim, it starts off with `:2R` already entered into the command line. I tried commenting out my entire `.vimrc`, and then it opens up starting in replace mode, with the 2 key pre-pressed (in other words, I insert some text, press `<ESC>`, and the text appears twice), which is the same as if I had pressed `2R` upon opening vim.

How should I go about debugging this? I don't think it can be an issue with my `.vimrc`, so then what could it be?

For reference, I just updated to version 8.2 via `ppa:jonathonf/vim`.

Comment: Are you using `<Esc>` in any mappings in your vimrc? In my answer here notice the reference to `2R`... [Why does terminal vim enter replace mode with my vimrc file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/19073)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful link. I do use `<ESC>` in some mappings, but never on the left-hand side. Further, commenting out the whole `.vimrc` does not stop the `2R` from occurring. I opened up vim with a fully-commented `.vimrc`, and used `:scriptnames` to find that the only other files loaded are `/usr/share/vim/vimrc`, `~/.vim/filetype.vim`, `~/.vimrc`, and some files from `/usr/share/vim/vim82/...`.

Comment: Hmm. That's surprising. What about when you start vim with `--clean`? If no issues with that then one of those files you listed has to be the culprit (assuming Vim launch is otherwise normal)

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using? What is the `$TERM` environment variable set to?

Comment: This is usually a problem with your terminal emulator and I think happens most often with terminals pretending to be `xterm` (check `$TERM`). Make sure to use a recent vim version (not sure if `jonathonf/vim` is still maintained). Might also try to use `:set t_u7=` and see if this fixes it.

Comment: The bug persists when running with `--clean`, but it does not when running with `-u NONE`. I am using WSL, and `echo $TERM` gives "`xterm-256color`." `:set t_u7` showed me that it was `^[[6n` by default. Adding `set t_u7=` to my `.vimrc` seems to fix the problem. Still not fully understanding what t_u7 is, even after reading `term.txt`, but thanks for the help!!

Comment: If you're using the right kind of terminal (e.g. true xterm) and you send it the special character sequence `<Esc>[6n` (note: `<Esc>` prints as `^[`) the terminal will reply with the cursor's current row and column. (From xterm terminal you can try it yourself with `echo -e "\e[6n"`.) The exact format of the response is `<Esc>r;cR`. If cursor is on column 2 then you can see where `2R` might come from. I'm not sure of exactly how, though, the mix of Vim and a terminal emulator with mediocre xterm emulation results in the output getting into Vim as a command.

Comment: Anyways, by unsetting `t_u7` you tell Vim not to use that special sequence anymore even though your TERM envvar indicates you are using some kind of terminal emulator compatible with xterm.

Comment: Just noticed you said WSL. I use it, too, (WSL 1 originally and now WSL 2). I don't see this problem. OTOH, I use mintty as my terminal emulator. If you're not doing so then switching to it will likely solve the problem without workarounds. (mintty is an excellent TE, FYI)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Is there a known bug around `t_u7`? Based on a bit of digging it seems to me that OPs TE is responding properly to the `CSI 6 n` request sent in src/term.c:`may_req_ambiguous_char_width()` but that response is being treated as typed characters.

Comment: Or perhaps the TE is sending the correct response but in an incorrect way (e.g. with an unexpected timing or delay), meaning the bug is not Vim's...  BTW, I see there was a patch for something that looks very similar but that was all the way back in 8.0.0611 and OP says they're using 8.2.

Comment: This is WSL? Good to know, would have been useful to mention at the beginning. It was talking about ppa, so I did not think about this. I believe this is a known problem of the Windows Terminal as mentioned here: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/6365 Note, this should have been fixed in the latest windows terminal release.

Comment: That must be it. And it _is_ essentially a timing issue. Send two control sequences and the responses come back simultaneously, so to speak, such that their individual characters get intermingled. (!!) Fixed Windows Terminal was released late September.

Comment: Thanks again for further explanations/info. I remap `;` to `:`, so it makes sense that some bug would cause `#;2R` to enter command mode as `:2R`. Also, with regard to the timing issue, I didn't mention it but ~1-2% of the times I opened vim, the issue wouldn't happen at all. Makes sense with the race condition mentioned. I will look into updating WSL and possibly switching to mintty. Thanks for educating me about some basic concepts here, like the fact that there are escape sequences handled by terminal emulators. In the meantime, would other parts of vim maybe break due to setting `t_u7=`?

Comment: From what I read and saw in the code that control sequence is used for just a single check at startup (related to character widths in Unicode encodings like utf-8) and thus shouldn't be a source of further problems.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I thought of adding an answer here since I have lots of data but you cracked the case vis a vis Windows Terminal...thus I think you should have the "right of first refusal"...

Comment: @BLayer no problem, please go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the question comments, this is a terminal emulator control sequence bug. The easiest fix is to install and use [WSLTTY](https://github.com/mintty/wsltty). Simply download the [latest release](https://github.com/mintty/wsltty/releases) and run the installer, then launch WSL from the newly-installed program.