# Shift+AnyLetter and Forward Slash Not Working on wsltty

Tags: key-bindings, terminal, insert-mode

I'm noticing errant behaviour with some standard key sequences with Vim 8.1 on wsltty. The correct behaviour is displayed when inside wsltty's standard terminal, so until proven otherwise I'm assuming it's an issue on Vim's end.

1. When I'm in insert mode and go to enter any uppercase letter by holding `Shift` and the relevent key, it maps to undo, i.e. performs the deletion/insertion and updates the status bar with a message like *'1 line less; before #4; 1 second ago'*
2. When I'm in insert mode and enter a forward slash, a new line is inserted above the current line with an 'o' at the beginning of it, e.g:

```
--BEFORE--
Some
words

are entered here█
--AFTER--
Some
words

o█
are entered here
```

My `.vimrc` is [here](https://github.com/ryan-mcclue/cas/blob/main/.vimrc). I have no mappings to these key sequences. They work correctly in command-line mode, normal mode and inside gvim. I'm truly puzzled as to the cause of this odd behaviour.

Comment: Three comments: try without the `<Esc>` mapping in insert mode; see [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604); (irrelevantly) you have some `<expr>` maps that use `?:` and the right-hand-side of the colon is not an `expr` (so you probably need to make it a string, like `'Q'`, etc.)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Altering the `<Esc>` mapping worked like a charm! Thank you! How was this causing the problem?

Comment: I’ll have to find my reference; short version is mapping esc causes problems.

Comment: This one is about mapping `<Esc>` on Normal mode, but it's not too far from the issue at hand here... https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2614/18609