# Mapping Esc makes vim open in REPLACE mode

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

I've enabled `hlsearch` to highlight text after searching,

```
$ grep hlsearch ~/.vimrc
set hlsearch
```

and now I want to clear the highlight, which I can do with `:noh`. [I saw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372660/get-rid-of-vims-highlight-after-searching-text#comment4768586_4372666) that I can assign this to `esc` key in normal mode with this:

```
$ grep noh ~/.vimrc
nnoremap <silent> <esc> :noh<cr><esc>
```

Now everytime I open vim, it opens in `-- REPLACE --` mode. How can I fix this?

The version of vim:

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Sep 15 2021 21:48:21)
Included patches: 1-3441
Compiled by Arch Linux
Huge version without GUI.
```

Comment: That mapping looks fine.   Which version of Vim are you using?   I tested this in Vim8.2.3364 with no problem.   

I even tried to add `normal R` at the end of my ~/.vimrc and Vim opened in NORMAL mode.

Comment: @ChrisHeithoff VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Sep 15 2021 21:48:21)

Comment: **Do not map `<esc>`!** (at least not until Vim has finally started up) https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2620/71

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I see. Thank you.